# XPath with Scrapy node begins with \n

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy on html like:

```
<td nowrap="" valign="top" align="right">
    <br>
    Text is here.
    <br>
    Other text is here
    <br>
</td>
```

td[1]/text()[1] gives me:

```
(empty line)
Text is here.
```

I've tried normalize-space, i.e. normalize-space(td[1]/text()[1]), which works when I test in my firefox extension, but not in scrapy. I think scrapy is getting tripped up by the \n and it skips over (or only takes first line of node, which is nothing). I've also tried some "preceding" and "following" code, but I think it might be considered one element, my DOM says the nodeValue = "\nText is here" Any thoughts?,

Comment: You haven't said what result you actually expect or want to get. In other words, what does "works" mean? Are you hoping to get an empty string? Are you hoping to get "Text is here. Other text is here."? Or something different?

Comment: I think we need a new acronym: WRDYW & WRDYG? What result did you want, and what result did you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract every text, get the desired one by index. For instance:

```
response.xpath("//table[@id='myid']/tr[1]/td[1]//text()")[1]
```

Demo from the Scrapy Shell:

```
$ scrapy shell http://www.trobar.org/troubadours/coms_de_peiteu/guilhen_de_peiteu_01.php
In [1]: table = response.xpath("//table")[2]
In [2]: td = "".join(table.xpath(".//td[1]//text()").extract())
In [3]: print(td)

Companho, farai un vers qu'er covinen,
Et aura-i mais de foudatz no-y a de sen,
Et er totz mesclatz d'amor e de joy e de joven.

E tenguatz lo per vilan qui no-l enten,
O dins son cor voluntiers non l'apren:
Greu partir si fai d'amor qui la troba a talen.

Dos cavalhs ai a ma sselha, ben e gen,
Bon son et adreg per armas e valen,
E no-ls puesc amdos tener, que l'us l'autre non cossen.

Si-ls pogues adomesjar a mon talen,
Ja no volgr'alhors mudar mon garnimen,
Que meils for'encavalguatz de nuill ome viven.

Launs fon dels montaniers lo plus corren,
Mas aitan fer' estranhez'a longuamen
Et es tan fers e salvatges, que del bailar si defen.

L'autre fon noyritz sa jus part Cofolen
Ez anc no-n vis bellazor, mon escien:
Aquest non er ja camjatz ni per aur ni per argen.

Qu'ie-l donei a son senhor polin payssen,
Pero si-m retinc ieu tan de covenen
Que, s'ilh lo tenia un an, qu'ieu lo tengues mais de cen.

Cavalier, datz mi cosselh d'un pessamen:
-Anc mays no fuy issaratz de cauzimen- :
Res non sai ab qual me tengua, de n'Agnes o de n'Arsen.

De Gimel ai lo castel e-l mandamen,
E per Niol fauc ergueill a tota gen:
C'ambedui me son jurat e plevit per sagramen.
```

Comment: When I extract using only td[1]/text()  I get an empty list "[]". So indexing is out of range.

Comment: @ChrisDH ok, what about `td[1]//text()`?

Comment: Also empty, the inital \n must be throwing it off, should we message and I can just actual link?

Comment: @ChrisDH yeah, please share an actual url so that I can try reproducing the problem instead of guessing. Thanks.

Comment: the link is http://www.trobar.org/troubadours/coms_de_peiteu/guilhen_de_peiteu_01.php I'm trying to get the left column, as well as the first line in the left column, so: /html/body/center/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/br[1]/following-sibling::text() and /html/body/center/table[2]/tbody/tr/td[1]/br[1]/following-sibling::text()[1], normalize-space works in browser but not scrapy

Comment: @ChrisDH thanks, please see the update with a working code.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! Not sure I understand it, but it works!